# java warning: Unchecked Call as a member of raw type when I supply the type

Tags: java, generics, java-8

When I initialize my class (ObjectGenerator)

```
Class classType = entityType.getClazz();
ObjectGenerator ext = new ObjectGenerator(fields, classType);
```

I get a compiler warning

```
Unchecked Call to ObjectGenerator....  as a member of raw type
```

When my class is declared as follows

```
public class ObjectGenerator<T>
     public ObjectGenerator(List<DualFieldWrapper> propertyToValuePair, Class<T> apiClass) {
```

Why is that?

BTW: adding

```
Class<?> classType = entityType.getClazz();
```

Doesnt work.

Comment: Class is generic - try something like `Class<?> classType = entityType.getClazz();` instead.

Comment: @assylias Thanks. It doesnt solve the worning.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the rest: Class is generic but so is ObjectGenerator. So you need something like `ObjectGenerator<?> ext = new ObjectGenerator<> (fields, classType);` If you know what type is returned by `entityType.getClazz()` you can replace the wildcard by an actual type.